# Formula where it shows the cell location for certain words in the list but with blanks. - Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formula

Is there a formula where if I have a list, for example, "Ready For Work" it will write down the cell location into 1 cell, but only if there is no one working on it (blank name) so that I can find the work easily?

My Formula I have so far is "=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(D:D),4,4),F:F=D1),)"

All I'm missing is the IFBLANK formula, but don't know how to implement it.

What I have so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIkV.png

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use conditional formatting to highlight those cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(A4:A8),1,4),B4:B8=A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to only add the cell reference if there was a name list in Column C. 
For example, if there were names next to the "Ready for Work" in Column B, it would ignore that and would only add references to only the blank names.

Comment: @den Can give a try to `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(A4:A8),1,4),(B4:B8=A1)*(C4:C8="")))`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

Screenshot:

[image]

Used formulae:

```
=IF(B2="a b c",ROW(),"")
=IF(NOT(C2=""),"B","")
=D2&C2
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,E2:E7)
```

(I would give some explanation, but it's self-explaining, I guess) :-)

Comment: Oops! I just see the answer of Harun. It's pretty clear that my answer has been written by someone who does not know the `Address()` function :-)